# Dia on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, unix, x11

I'm trying to run Dia on macOS Sierra (MacBookPro, Retina). It crashed searching for `libdia.dylib`. Exporting `Display=:0`, as recommended [here](http://navkirats.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/dia-diagram-mac-osx-yosemite-fix-i-use.html), does not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: For me, adding `export DISPLAY=:0` below line 39 in `Dia.app/Contents/Resources/bin` did the trick. One solution for you is to run it inside an Ubuntu VM in Virtualbox.

Comment: I verify that this solution also works for `macOS Catalina`